# Calling get request on init

Tags: angularjs, http, get

This is my controller page

```
.controller('ActorController',function($scope,$q,$http) {

   $scope.showActors = false;
   var POPULAR_PERSON = 'person/popular';

    var actors = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
        actors.push($http.get(URL + POPULAR_PERSON + APIKEY + PAGE + i))
    }
    $q.all(actors).then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.actors = response[0].data.results;
            $scope.showActors = true;

            for(var j = 1; j < response.length; j++) {
                $scope.actors = $scope.actors.concat(response[j].data.results);
            }
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
        }
    )

    $scope.getActorDetails = function(id){
        var actorDetails = $http.get(URL + "person/" + id + APIKEY);
        actorDetails.then(
            function(response){
                console.log(response.data.biography);
                $scope.actorDetails = response.data.biography;
            }
        )
    }
})
```

Both the get request is working properly. This controller gets the actor information and the function getActorDetails() gets the biography of the particular actor using the id.

This is my HTML page

```
<div ng-controller="ActorController">
<div class="actors-list row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="!showActors">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
<ul class="actors-list media-list">
    <li class="media" dir-paginate="actor in actors | itemsPerPage:5">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a>
                    <img class="media-object img-responsive"
                         ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{{actor.profile_path}}" width=180 height=300 alt="{{actor.name}}">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading"><a class="movie-title">{{actor.name}}</a></h2>
<span> TO BE INSERTED <span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="10"
            direction-links="true"
            boundary-links="true">
    </dir-pagination-controls>
</ul>
```

How to insert the function getActorDetails() in the "TO BE INSERTED" so that I can get the actor details of the particular actor.

P.S : function to be passed getActorDetails(actor.id). The function should get called as soon as the page loads. How to call a function without clicking any buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try `ng-init`:

```
<span ng-init="getActorDetails(actor.id)"> TO BE INSERTED <span>
```

But you should store the details in a map:

```
$scope.actorDetails = {};//declare this at the beginning of your controller
```

and in the `getActorDetails` then:

```
$scope.getActorDetails = function(actor){
    var actorDetails = $http.get(URL + "person/" + actor.id + APIKEY);
    actorDetails.then(
        function(response){
            console.log(response.data.biography);
            $scope.actorDetails[id] = response.data.biography;//stored in a map
        }
    )
}
```

And the `span`

```
<span ng-init="getActorDetails(actor.id)"> <!-- display data binded to actorDetails[actor.id] --> <span>
```

Another way would be to fetch the data for each actor and store it into the actor but since you are using page I guess that would be bad:

```
for(var j = 1; j < response.length; j++) {
    $scope.actors = $scope.actors.concat(response[j].data.results);
}
angular.forEach($scope.actors, function(actor){
    $scope.getActorDetails(actor);
});

$scope.getActorDetails = function(actor){
    var actorDetails = $http.get(URL + "person/" + actor.id + APIKEY);
    actorDetails.then(
        function(response){
            console.log(response.data.biography);
            $scope.actorDetails = response.data.biography;
        }
    )
}
```

To call a function on page load I usually use:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    //stuff
});
```

Or if I use a component (since angular 1.5), I use the `$onInit`:

```
.controller('ActorController',function($q,$http) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.$onInit = function(){
        //stuff
    }
});
```

Note than instead of binding to `$scope` when using this approach, you should bind to ctrl.

Here with a component:

```
.component('actorDetails', {
    bindings: {
        id: '<'
    },
    template: 'yourTemplate',
    controller: ['$http', function ($http) {
        var ctrl = this;

        var URL = 'yourURL';
        var APIKEY = 'yourAPIKEY';

        ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            var actorDetails = $http.get(URL + "person/" + ctrl.id + APIKEY);
            actorDetails.then(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data.biography);
                        ctrl.actorDetails = response.data.biography;
                    }
            );
        };
    }]
});
```

and html, instead of:

```
<span> TO BE INSERTED <span>
```

call your component:

```
<actor-details id="actor.id"></actor-details>
```

Comment: ng-init is working. But the same details is repeating for all actors. Do we have to introduce ng-repeat again for the function getActorDetails() or how should I proceed ? Because id for all the actors is not inside this function !

Comment: updated my answer with the ng-init, you are storing details of the last getActorDetails into $scope.actorDetails while you should store for each actor.

Comment: Best approach would be to use the component (reusable easily)

Comment: I had done it already but I updated it again so it will be easier to unterstand

Comment: I'm not getting it.What exactly I've to write in between the span ? Should it be 

<p ng-init="getActorDetails(actor.id)">{{actorDetails}}</p>

Comment: Id depends on what you want to display but no, {{actorDetails}} contains details for all actors (it is defined as a map). You should display {{actorDetails[actor.id]}} instead to get the right object. Read the answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

call your getActorDetails method from the success callback of your getActors call and store the details in the actors object itself.

```
.controller('ActorController', function($scope, $q, $http) {
    $scope.showActors = false;
    var POPULAR_PERSON = 'person/popular';

    var actors = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        actors.push($http.get(URL + POPULAR_PERSON + APIKEY + PAGE + i))
    }
    $q.all(actors).then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.actors = response[0].data.results;
            $scope.showActors = true;

            for (var j = 1; j < response.length; j++) {
                $scope.actors = $scope.actors.concat(response[j].data.results);
            }
            angular.forEach($scope.actors, function(actor) {
                getActorDetails(actor.id).then(function() { // resolve promise here and assign the value to $scope.actor object.
                    actor.actorDetails = response.data;
                })
            });
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message = "Error: " + response.status + " " + response.statusText;
        }
    )

    var getActorDetails = function(id) {
        var actorDetails = $http.get(URL + "person/" + id + APIKEY);
        actorDetails.then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data.biography);
        });
        return actorDetails; // return promise here
    }
})
```

bind this actorDetails object on HTML.

```
<div ng-controller="ActorController">
<div class="actors-list row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-if="!showActors">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
<ul class="actors-list media-list">
    <li class="media" dir-paginate="actor in actors | itemsPerPage:5">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a>
                    <img class="media-object img-responsive"
                         ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{{actor.profile_path}}" width=180 height=300 alt="{{actor.name}}">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading"><a class="movie-title">{{actor.name}}</a></h2>
<span> {{actor.actorDetail.biography}} <span>
</div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <dir-pagination-controls
            max-size="10"
            direction-links="true"
            boundary-links="true">
    </dir-pagination-controls>
</ul>
```

Remove your getActorDetails method from scope.
Also, you have your actor details for future use as well in `$scope.actors` object

Comment: This is already in my answer and suggested as bad since he will fetch the data for all actors while he is displaying only 5.